# Superponer un DIV y deshabilitar el fondo

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3, popup

Me encuentro con un problema y no puedo dar con una solución.
Resulta que estoy haciendo una galería especie portfolio, en donde el usuario clickea sobre una miniatura del trabajo para visualizarlo. El tema es que al clickear, se abre un **div** con un **iframe** dentro, ya que el portfolio incluye juegos y aplicaciones interactivas.
El problema surge en que aunque haya creado un div contenedor con posición fija y transparencia para bloquear el fondo, aún puedo scrollear e incluso clickear, dificultando la interacción con el div abierto.
A alguien se le ocurre una solución a esto? Mi último recurso es si no, usar modals, pero tengo entendido que con los modals no puedo interactuar con los proyectos de juegos que subí.

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Dejo el código usado:

```js
document.getElementById("popup").showpopup = function() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('iframe').src = "http://misitio.com/test/project1/";
  document.getElementById('page').className = "darken";
  document.getElementById("page").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("popup").showpopup();
}

document.getElementById('page').onclick = function() {
  if (document.getElementById("popup").style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("page").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('page').className = "";
  }
};
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 300;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -280px;
  margin-left: -160px;
}

#page {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 90;
  position: fixed;
}

.darken {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 80;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.close-icon {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%, white 56%, transparent 56%, transparent 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%, white 56%, transparent 56%, transparent 100%);
  background-color: gray;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 400;
}
```

```html
<div id="ad1" class="portfolio-item deporte col-md-3">
  <div class="portfolio-box">
    <a href="" id="a">
      <div class="portfolio-image-wrap">
        <img src="img/portfolio/proyecto1.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio-caption-mask">
        <div class="portfolio-caption-text">
          <div class="portfolio-caption-tb-cell">
            <h5 class="alt-title">Nombre del proyecto</h5>
            <p>Descripción</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div id="page">
      <div id="popup">
        <a href="#/" class="close-icon"></a>
        <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola!

El truco es hacer que el contenido que no quieras que se mueva tenga el estilo `overflow` en `hidden`, en lugar del default que es `visible` (y que en consecuencia habilita la navegación con scrollbars).

Agregando lo siguiente a tu método `showpopup`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Y lo siguiente a tu método `onclick` (al cerrarse el popup):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
```

Vas a lograr lo que querés.

Referencias: [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) y [StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19701469/4150202)

Comment: Hola! Genial, ahora intentaré hacer lo que me dijiste. El estilo overflow tendría que agregarlo al body, o al div en negro que lo superpone? Es lo único en lo que me quedó duda.

Comment: @CarlaPaludetto si querés que tooodo el fondo se deje de mover, el overflow hidden va en el body

Comment: Genial, ahora lo voy a intentar. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Alf Sanzo, hice lo que me dijiste y funcionó perfectamente. Quería saber si existía alguna manera de también bloquear el click fuera del div popup, y que solo se pueda cerrar a través del botón para cerrar

Comment: @CarlaPaludetto hoy la línea `document.getElementById('page').onclick = ` registra el evento onclick en todo el div del popup. Para que el click sólo funcione en la cruz debés registrarlo sólo en ese elemento. Por ejemplo, en lugar de 'page' registrarlo así: `document.getElementsByClassName("close-icon")[0].onclick = ...`

Comment: Hola Alf Sanzo, tanto tiempo. Quería comentarte que luego de un tiempo, esta opción para bloquear el scroll del body cuando se abre el popup ya no funciona, y scrollea de todos modos, dificultando la interacción con el juego dentro del iframe. Quería saber si había alguna otra manera de lograr lo mismo. Saludos

Comment: Hola @CarlaPaludetto !! Hay muchas cosas que pueden haber interferido con la solución. ¿Por qué no abrís otra pregunta con todos los datos necesarios para que lo podamos analizar?

Comment: Hola! Buena idea, ahora abro una nueva pregunta! Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

bueno yo como solo se SVG todo lo resuelvo con svg, si haces un svg que sirva de galeria, y asi el fondo queda opacado por el svg y dejaria de ser scrollable o clickeable, y puedes manejar la transparencia del svg y los eventos del mouse y lo que necesites el svg puedes nuevamente incrustar divs usando objetos foraneos.

```
<foraignobject>
</foraignobject>
```